# How to place successive rows as a list besides Pandas dataframe original rows based on a specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a Pandas `dataframe` of the following format, which consists of a `ColumnA` with entries, and an `IsMatching` Column with True/False values.

```
       ColumnA                IsMatching
0.     asdasdas                 True
1.     bsdasdas                 False
2.     csdasdas                 False
3.     dsdasdas                 True
4.     4455sdas                 False
5.     asdasdas                 False
6.     ppdasdas                 False
7.     jjdasdas                 True
...
```

The aim is to create a new `dataframe` column `(NewColumn)`, which contains `ColumnA` elements in between the 2 `True` instances as a `list` (wherever a `True` occurs in `IsMatching` Column, the `list` needs to be placed there, otherwise, the `NewColumn` values should be kept empty).

```
               ColumnA                   NewColumn                                IsMatching
        0.     asdasdas                 [bsdasdas,csdasdas] # As 2 Falses          True
    between dataframe indices 0 and 3.
        1.     bsdasdas                  Keep This Empty                           False
        2.     csdasdas                  Keep This Empty                           False
        3.     dsdasdas                 [4455sdas,asdasdas,ppdasdas] # As 3 Falses 
between dataframe indices 3 and 7.
        4.     esdasdas                ....
```

Any suggestions and help in achieving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try until now ? This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235312/how-to-implodereverse-of-pandas-explode-based-on-a-column

Comment: @SpaceBurger thanks for the comment and the link to the related question. This is helpful, but the method seems to implode successive rows as a list, without any condition. As I want my list elements to be in between 2 Pandas rows based on conditions, I cannot infer how this `groupby` method can be used with conditions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add an addition column that are groups of rows that belong together **key**
- generate a `list` of **ColumnA** values against `False`
- `merge()` it back to row in same **key** where **IsMatching** is `True`

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""       ColumnA                IsMatching
0.     asdasdas                 True
1.     bsdasdas                 False
2.     csdasdas                 False
3.     dsdasdas                 True
4.     4455sdas                 False
5.     asdasdas                 False
6.     ppdasdas                 False
7.     jjdasdas                 True"""), sep="\s+")
df = df.reindex(df.index.astype(int))

df = df.assign(key=df.IsMatching.cumsum())
df = df.merge(df.loc[~df.IsMatching].assign(IsMatching=True).groupby(["IsMatching","key"])["ColumnA"].agg(NewColumn=list), 
         left_on=["IsMatching","key"], right_index=True, how="left").drop(columns="key")
```

|  | ColumnA | IsMatching | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | asdasdas | True | ['bsdasdas', 'csdasdas'] |
| 1 | bsdasdas | False | nan |
| 2 | csdasdas | False | nan |
| 3 | dsdasdas | True | ['4455sdas', 'asdasdas', 'ppdasdas'] |
| 4 | 4455sdas | False | nan |
| 5 | asdasdas | False | nan |
| 6 | ppdasdas | False | nan |
| 7 | jjdasdas | True | nan |