# Reverse explode with dummy df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I've been trying to use reverse explode from here: [How to implode(reverse of pandas explode) based on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235312/how-to-implodereverse-of-pandas-explode-based-on-a-column)

But I have a little bit different df.

I have df looking like this:

[image]

I need to 'reverse explode' it, but I couldn't find any option to *groupby* by index. Is there any option to do that?

To be precise, I need all columns to remain, but all '1' should be combined in a row.
I merged dummy df with main df, but can not figure out what to do next.

```
rest_cuisine_style = pd.concat([rest_cuisine_style, cuisine_dummies], axis=1)
```

Comment: maybe that would help : 
df.groupby(df.index).max()

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
rest_cuisine_style = rest_cuisine_style.idxmax(axis=1)
```