# Remove duplicate values in each row of the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame, which has a column that shows repeated values. It was the result of an inverse "explode" operation... `trello_dataframe = trello_dataframe.groupby(['Card ID', 'ID List'], as_index=True).agg({'Member (Full Name)': lambda x: x.tolist()})`

How do I remove duplicate values in each row of the column?

I attach more information: https://prnt.sc/RjGazPcMBX47

I would like to have the data frame like this: https://prnt.sc/y0VjKuewp872

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to target the column and with a np.unique

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Column1' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Column2' : [[5, 0, 5, 0, 5], [5,0,5], [5]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].apply(lambda x : np.unique(x))
df
```

Comment: The column 2 looks familiar to me somewhere :D

Comment: Hi,  
ArchAngelPwn,   Great! It works perfectly!

Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If you liked the answer please make sure to hit the "answered" so others might be able to find the answer as well