# I want to join data from a dataframe by customer id (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (pandas python) in this format:

| ID | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 3 | 11 |

What I want to do is join the data by id into a list so that it looks like this:

| ID | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [15,10,25] |
| 2 | 13 |
| 3 | [10,11] |

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implode(reverse of pandas explode) based on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235312/how-to-implodereverse-of-pandas-explode-based-on-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df2 = df.groupby('ID', as_index = False)['Valor'].agg(list)
```